# Please undelete this question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

This question was deleted 6 years ago by a moderator:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436159/how-to-get-all-subclasses/

In my opinion it meets all the criteria as outlined in our help page:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Not only that but it has some really great answers which solve the problem in various ways and will certainly be helpful to others.

My best guess is that it was removed because it doesn't focus on a specific programming language but I'm not sure that is or should be a problem in this case. Since it was deleted by a mod, I am unable to even *cast a vote* to undelete it.  Can we discuss undeleting it please?

Comment: For that question, there could be a potential new answer for every single programming language that implements subclassing. I don't know about the deletion, but it does seem way too broad to remain open to me.

Comment: There are only so many programming languages - in your opinion, why is that a problem? At the very least I feel it should be visible, even if we keep it closed.

Comment: the questions is too broad, and is correctly closed, the deletion can be discussed, but i doubt that after that much time someone will miss it without asking a new question with much more focus

Comment: @nbk - thanks.  And yes, as mentioned, that's exactly what I want to discuss. Undeleting it.

Comment: "There are only so many programming languages" - Ha ha :) I have to quote a popular TV show that most programmers will probably know: "I'm sorry, are you from the past!?"

Answer (score 14):

## No.

The question wants a grab bag of snippets which are broad and don't have any definition of "right".  Each question asked should have a reasonable definition of "answerable", and for every new OO language that pops up, a new answer needs to be put into place.  Note that in the time this question was asked, Kotlin was borne as a new JVM language, and another answer to get at that would need to be added to this grab-bag.

## No thank you.

---

Besides, the answers to this question exist in other reasonably scoped questions.

[How to find all direct subclasses of a class with .NET Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038819/how-to-find-all-direct-subclasses-of-a-class-with-net-reflection/16038881)

[How to find all the subclasses of a class given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862310/how-to-find-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class-given-its-name)

[Look up all descendants of a class in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby)

[How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java)

[how to obtain all subclasses of a class in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470008/how-to-obtain-all-subclasses-of-a-class-in-php)

Comment: \*[born](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bear#Usage_notes) (*"when bear is used in the passive voice to mean "to be given birth to" literally or figuratively (e.g. be created, be the result of), the form used to form all tenses is born"*)

Comment: The edit button is still in working order, @PeterMortensen.